# Using multiple colors in matplotlib plot

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib, plot

I have a numpy array of 2D data points (x,y), which are classified into three categories (0,1,2).

```
a = array([[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
           [ 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 ]])

class = array([0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0])
```

My question is if I can plot these points with multiple colors. I would like to do something like this:

```
colors = list()
for i in class:
    if i == 0:
        colors.append('r')
    elif i == 1:
        colors.append('g')
    else:
        colors.append('b')

print colors
['r', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'r']

pp.plot(a[0], a[1], color = colors)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I assume you want to plot distinct points. In that case,
if you define a numpy array:

```
colormap = np.array(['r', 'g', 'b'])
```

then you can generate the array of colors with `colormap[categories]`:

```
In [18]: colormap[categories]
Out[18]: 
array(['r', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'r'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
              [ 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 ]])

categories = np.array([0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0])

colormap = np.array(['r', 'g', 'b'])

plt.scatter(a[0], a[1], s=50, c=colormap[categories])
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]